# Edit link arround the contents missing

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to orchard CMS. I have downloaded the source code from http://orchardproject.net/ .  I am not able to find the Edit link around the contents as in the screen shots provided.  I have worked on Sitecore and now I am in process to find new Open source CMS for my client. Is this link provide me an inline editor? I would like to explore more.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to enable the **Content Control Wrapper** and/or **Widget Control Wrapper** features in "Modules" screen. **Since 1.4** those features are optional.

Regarding the "inline" editor question - no, there's currently no inline editing feature in Orchard. Enabling the mentioned features will only make the "Edit" links appear on the front end. Clicking those will redirect you to appropriate edit screen in the admin Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

In Orchard 1.9 I faced with problem when I click on "Enable" on Content Control Wrapper and Widget Control Wrapper ... everytime I got "Oops ... something is went wrong".

Workaround:
Filter modules by entering Wrapper into filter textbox, place a tick into both checboxes, select "Enable" in Actions dropdown and then Execute.
It enables both modules and no error message appears.