# Why are the EDIT buttons missing from the Orchard Zones (when logged in as Admin)?

Tags: orchardcms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit link arround the contents missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565814/edit-link-arround-the-contents-missing)

I am learning how to use Orchard CMS using some online video tutorials.  All of the tutorials show that when you are logged in as an Admin each zone on a page has box around it and has an Edit button in the upper right corner.

For both myself and another developer neither the box or the Edit button is showing.  We are using Orchard 1.4.  I am using Orchard in Visual Studio from source.  The other developer is using Web Matrix.

Can someone tell me how to get the box and edit button or was that removed for version 1.4?  Or is it something else?

Seth

Comment: You can find your answer in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565814/edit-link-arround-the-contents-missing

Answer (score 15):

They are turned off by default.

To turn it on try enabling and disabling the Content Control Wrapper and Widget Control Wrapper Features within the Modules Section of the Orchard Dashboard.